# How fill a dbcombo with all the records of a specific field visual basic 6

Tags: data-binding, combobox, vb6

I need to fill the full dbcombo with all the records the a specific field in visual basic 6. I joined that dbcombo with a data control and I specified the property called datafield, but the dbcombo show only a record
Can something help me please?

I want the contents of the combobox to show Select * from students" in sql.

I have the datasource of the controldata point to "students.mdb"

Comment: Did you set the datasource?

Comment: What do you mean by "Showing only a record"?

Comment: yes,but I need.  "Select * from students" in sql. I have the datasource of the controldata point to  "students.mdb", the dbcombo shows the first record of the table students. I need all the records of the table, a below the other, showing the field name of student

Comment: If you hit the arrows on the Data control, you will see that it shows different records as you move around.  So, the way you have it set up, it only shows the current record that the cursor is pointing to.  See my answer below for how to fix this the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the different properties in the DBCombo box.  There are four properties you need to be aware of:

1. DataSource
2. DataField
3. RowSource
4. ListField

To get the list you want, you need to set the RowSource to the Data Control, and the ListField to the field you want, in your case Students.

DataSource and DataField you only need if you are going to be updating the underlying database.  DataSource is again the Data Control, and DataField is which field you want to update--it doesn't need to be the same field as the ListField.