# populating VB6 Combo Box Items

Tags: sql-server, combobox, vb6

how do i get all items to display in a VB6 Combo box that gets data from the Database.

I Only see one topmost item.

i tried changing the combo box style but nothing is working

Comment: can u post your code

Comment: For this particular combo box am using only properties. Ive set the datasource and datamember and the field to be displayed. Nb: all this is in Vb6.0

Comment: @user1844933 For this particular combo box am using only properties. Ive set the datasource and datamember and the field to be displayed. Nb: all this is in Vb6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724931/how-fill-a-dbcombo-with-all-the-records-of-a-specific-field-visual-basic-6/31819629#31819629) a couple of days ago (presumably you are also using a Data control; if you are not then mention that and I'll work out another answer).  DataSource and DataMember are the wrong properties to be working with.  I explain why fully in the other answer.